# Does anyone know the name of this series? I believe I first read them almost 10 years ago

Tags: story-identification

I have an absolutely terrible memory and could be conflating several plots here, but all I can remember is that there was some sort of virus or disease or something that was wiping out a majority of the population, and there were people that were born with different genetics and somehow able to adapt to survive.

I remember in the end there were like 5-9 people left and they chose what continents they wanted to inhabit and attempt to repopulate the earth. Being that they thought they were the only people left.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Hi Nina. Disease wiping out almost everyone on Earth is such a common theme in SF that it's going to be hard to identify your book. Anything you can remember will help e.g. character names or any unusual events in the story.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly the Idlewild series by Nick Sagan..

Wiki extract from the plot of book 2 *[Edenborn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edenborn)*:

> In the aftermath of a global plague and the death of all humans, a group of genetically altered posthumans raised in IVR, or Immersive Virtual Reality, are trying to rebuild society by cloning children.

Comment: Thank you all!! I'm like 99% certain that it is indeed the Idlewild series. I will have to reread them to make sure, but I felt a strong tinge of familiarity with that name and plot: ) thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: @Nina  you can click on the tick symbol to accept if you are sure